# Can only specify whole numbers as dimensions for printing

Tags: release-freya, printer

When I try to print a picture in a specific size, I can only set the dimensions to whole numbers like 19.00, not 18.50 or 19.2.
It's the same for cm and inches.
What can I do to make it work? Is this intended? Thanks for any help.

[Here is a video of it](https://vid.me/89Au).